# Conversion from Scala String to java.lang.String

Tags: scala, type-conversion

How do i convert a Scala string to a java.lang String.

I have to create a java.net.URL Object from a scala String. How do i do the conversion from a scala String to java.lang.String to pass to the URL constructor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to do any conversion. Simply pass a String to the URL constructor.

If you look at the [`scala.Predef` String definition](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L85) you will see this is exactly the same type.

```
package scala
object Predef extends scala.LowPriorityImplicits {
  // ...
  type String = java.lang.String
  // ...
}
```